# Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/fteproxy.bin --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, pluggable-transports

I am on an ethernet ADSL line. I started with Tor today and this is what it shared. But before that I need to share alias of Tor otherwise people would be left asking how Tor started.

```
$ alias tor
alias tor='/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser'
```

So starting Tor via CLI :-

```
$ tor

Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US

(process:5528): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:5528): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:5528): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:5528): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:5528): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Sep 04 21:02:12.892 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.23 (git-a9ea51dc0bd48126) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1i.
Sep 04 21:02:12.892 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 04 21:02:12.892 [notice] Read configuration file "/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults".
Sep 04 21:02:12.892 [notice] Read configuration file "/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/torrc".
Sep 04 21:02:12.895 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:xxxx
Sep 04 21:02:12.895 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:xxxx
Sep 04 21:02:12.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/fteproxy.bin --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 04 21:02:12.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/obfsproxy.bin managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 04 21:02:12.000 [notice] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec ./Tor/PluggableTransports/flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched.
Sep 04 21:02:12.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/geoip.
```

I have obfuscated the ports it is using by putting xxxx therein.

Looking forward to know more.